# Populate a UITableView with data retrieved from a NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsurlconnection

Basically I have a main screen that has a button on it, when you click on that button I want to load a list of users from a server and display them on the next screen in the tableview.

I can get the data with no issues, and pass it to my tableview with no issues - my problem lies with loading the data into the cells after I have received the data!

Processes exist like this:

- Tap button
- Starts NSURLConnection
- Opens up UITableView on screen
- Loads nothing
- Data returns, adds to NSArray
- Tableview Reload
- In viewWillAppear - make local users NSArray equal received Data

Nothing loads.

If I then press back, then press the button again, all my cells are populated with the data I received before.

Thanks in advance for any help. I've been searching around for a while now :(

**Edit:**

When moving from main screen to the tableview
Note: getUsers sets up the NSURLConnection and starts the connection

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"selectUser"]) {
        DDNetworkRequest *networkRequest = [[DDNetworkRequest alloc] init];
        [networkRequest getUsers];
    }
}
```

Tableview class:
Note: returnUserList just returns the array of data which is set as a variable within the network class

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    DDNetworkRequest *networkRequest = [[DDNetworkRequest alloc] init];
    users = [networkRequest returnUserList];
}
```

Network Class:
note: returnUsers manipulates and then saves the NSArray variable

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary;
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
       [usersJSONDict isEqualToDictionary: jsonDictionary];
       [self returnUsers:jsonDictionary];

       DDUserMessage *userMessageTable = [[DDUserMessage alloc] init];
       [userMessageTable.tableView reloadData];

}
```

** Edit2 **
returnUser method

```
-(void) returnUsers:(NSDictionary*)userDict{
    userListArray = [userDict valueForKey:@"username"];
}
```

Comment: Do you load the data asynchronously, as generally suggested? Please share some code with it. You may convert the data into the NSArray in other methods too. viewWillAppear is ok for each appearance of the view but it may not be the only place where it is needed.

Comment: Added code. I've also tried reloadData in the tableview class as well after I save the NSArray in the viewWillAppear method

Comment: in or following `didReceiveData` where do you actually refresh the NSArray that your table data source uses to populate the data?

Comment: Assumably, the NSArray will be refreshed in the viewWillAppear because that is being reloaded.

Comment: What is the sense in `[usersJSONDict isEqualToDictionary: jsonDictionary];`? That statement compares the two dictionaries and returns YES or NO. But the return value is never used!!!. And what does `returnUsers`do?

Comment: viewWillAppear will ALLWAYS creat a new and empty `networkRequest` and set the `users` array as empty array. `viewWillAppear` is called every time when a view comes into sight. That includes returns from subsequent view controllers or the user switching views in a tab view.

Comment: prepareForSegue is kinda senseless too. First you create - again - a new and empty object of any kind. Then you peform a getter on that brand new instance of something and then you discard the result of the getter. What is the sense in that?

Comment: No, viewWillAppear does not refresh the array (if it is an array at all). It assignes an empty array to `users` unless you have a very smart `init` method in `DDNetworkRequest`.

Comment: isEqualToDictionary was leftover code from something else. Added code for returnUsers.

Comment: Ok I understand everything you said. But I'm confused as to why the NSArray users shows up after pressing back and going back into the tableview??

Comment: Well, it is maybe my understanding that is wrong. Does DDNetworkRequest init do something actually? Does init return anything but an inititlized (but empty) object? If so then your code makes sense but then you would not follow the usual conventions which makes helping you quite difficult. Please share the code of that init mehtod (and alloc if you dared subclassing alloc :-)

Comment: No the init doesn't really do anything. I just alloc init it so I can use it as a variable and call the methods.

Comment: Well, if the init does not do anything, where do you expect the data to come from when you call `[networkRequest getUsers]` or `[networkRequest returnUserList]`? I guess you have some better code in viewDidLoad or so that actually shows some data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code provided from your side, I guess u forgot this awesome operation inside  the HTTP get request **success block**:

```
[self.tableView loadData];
```

M I RIGHT? ;)

Comment: Well, I thought the same myself, but hhis 6th bullet point sais "Tableview Reload".

Answer (score 1):

After you receive the data, you have to pass it to the data source array, then call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Also make sure you call this line from the main thread. You cannot make changes to UI from another thread.